# How to use Dijkstra's algorithm to generate an undirected, unweighted graph of a given diameter?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory, dijkstra

My job is to generate a random undirected, unweighted graph with a given diameter `d`. What I did already is to generate a random distance matrix `D` where each element `Dij` represents the distance between the `i-th` and `j-th` vertices of the graph. So, basically I am doing this:

```java
if (i == j) {
    D[i][j] = 0;
} else {
    D[i][j] = D[j][i] = random.nextInt(d + 1);
}
```

The diagonal is zero because it always needs zero effort to reach the same vertex, am I right?

Also, `Dij = Dji` because it is undirected. Are my assumptions right?

I want to use java, but I tagged the question as `language-agnostic` because I need an algorithm and not a code.

My next step is to use Dijkstra's algorithm to generate a random graph by generating an adjacency matrix. I think that Dijkstra's algorithm is to find the shortest path, but can I use it for my case?

**EDIT #1:**

[image: Example for distance matrix]

As you can see in the figure above, the diameter is 4 because the most distanced vertices are 2 and 7 have a distance of 4. For that reason, we have `D[2][7] = D[7][2] = 4`. Another example is `D[3][6] = D[6][3] = 2`, because if we want to go from 3 to 6, we can go 3 -> 5 -> 6, or 3 -> 1 -> 6 and vice versa for going from 6 to 3.

What I am looking for is to generate a random graph by knowing the diameter which is the maximum distance between two vertices in the graph. I know there are a lot of possibilities of the graph, but I need any of them.

I have an idea which is assuming that the number of vertices is `d + 1`, then connecting each vertex to the following vertex. In this case we will have a linear graph.

Example (diameter = 2, number of vertices = 3):

| v | ***1*** | ***2*** | ***3*** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***1*** | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| ***2*** | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| ***3*** | 2 | 1 | 0 |

1. The diagonal = zero
2. `D1,2 = D2,1 = D2,3 = D3,2 = 1`, because to go from 1 to 2, or 2 to 3, there is a direct link
3. `D1,3 = D3,1 = 2`, because to go from 1 to 3, the shortest path is 1
   -> 2 -> 3

Here is the graph associated to the above distance matrix:

[image: Graph]

I am looking for a better approach.

Comment: *I think that Dijkstra's algorithm is to find the shortest path* - yes. *"but can I use it for my case?"* - if you want to find a shortest path, then yes... so do you? Or do you want to generate a graph? Other than that, if your graph is supposed to be unweighted then it doesn't make sense to choose random weights, the weights of all edges should just be 1.

Comment: @kaya3 I want to have a diameter of `d`, which means the most distance would be `d`. It is unweighted, so each link costs 1 as you have said. What I mean by `Dij = 3` for an example is that to reach from i-th vetex to j-th vertex, then you have to pass through 2 vertices. Example: `D1,3 = 3`, then the route can be 1->5->7->3, or 1->2->4->3, or whatever. The route is random that I want to generate in my code. Diameter is the shortest path between the most two distanced vertices in the graph. https://transportgeography.org/contents/methods/graph-theory-measures-indices/diameter-graph/

Comment: @kaya3 To be more clear, `D` is not an adjacency matrix, it is a distance matrix. If `M` is an adjacency matrix, then `Mi,j = 3` means that there is a direct edge between `vertex i` and `vertex j` which its weight is 3. If `D` is a distance matrix, then `Di,j = 3` means that to reach from `vertex i` to `vertex j` or vice versa, then you need to pass through 2 vertices and 3 edges.

Comment: How can you expect it to be a distance matrix if you fill it with random numbers?

Comment: @kaya3 I want to fill the distance matrix with random numbers then generate a random graph based on that distance matrix where the most distanced shortest path will be of length `d`.

Comment: Random numbers are not going to make a distance matrix; distance matrices must satisfy the triangle inequality, and even that is far from sufficient if you want your matrix to be the distance matrix for an *unweighted* graph. Trying to define a graph by a distance matrix in the first place is an unworkable approach; your distance matrix is going to have 1s where the edges are, and every other element then *must* be the distance along those edges, so you cannot freely choose the matrix elements that are greater than 1.

Comment: @kaya3 I editted my question for more clarification.